# USB Endpoint Stalled Error

Tags: usb, endpoints, endpoint, usbserial

I am getting "endpoint stalled error" in my CDC device. The usb stack is detecting the cable. The state is set as running but the errorcode is set as 0x11 which indicates 'USB_ENDPOINT_STALLED'. I verified and found that the endpoints has been assigned properly.

1. What would be scenarios when "endpoint stalled error" would be reported?
2. How to handle this?

Please advise!

Answer (score 5):

STALL is a very common error and there is no general answer on this. You can [reset the pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa490269.aspx) , but i doubt it will help, probably your device is returning stall because your are not operating the device correctly.
Do you have an USB bus analyzer ? If yes please post the log so we can assist you better if not you can use a software bus analyzers like [usb snoop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/).